# Yii2 Check in query if values exists as opposite

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, yii2

I'm Making a Friends System that Checks if a User is Invited/Requested and Accepted by having the Record in the DB twice,

Table; friends

```
  user_id - friend_id
      1   -   2
      2   -   1
      3   -   1
```

in this case 1 and 2 SHOULD be Friends and 1 has a Request from 3
The one thing that i'm missing here is a Check that (with using SearchModel) can see if User 1 is IN User 2 his list AND that user 2 is IN user 1 his list.

This is my Function Search Right now;

```
   public function search($params)
{

    $query = Sportbuddies::find()
        ->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
        ->orWhere(['friend_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
    // Filter that ONLY shows the Entries where both User_id AND Friend_id
       have the same record in Reverse

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'friend_id' => $this->friend_id,
    ]);


    return $dataProvider;
}
```

This Currently Grabs all Records That EITHER have User_id or Friend_id AS Current User, But i'm Missing the Comparison part.

Comment: Isn' it easier for `friends` have 2 extra boolean fields to confirm the friend request for each user? that way it simplifies the code needed.

Comment: Ye, i've changed it now with a single boolean field even, because the user_id is Requestee and Friend_id is the Invited i just need an 'Accepted' Boolean. simplified the code and it works much faster xD Tnx